# iTunes Connect - After Removing an Application

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

due to a Licence Conflict with the Name of one of my Applications I had to remove it from the App Store.

If I rerelease it under a different name, is there a way I could reduce the price for people who previously bought the old App?

I'm going to add a lot of new features , still it is going to be the same program.

Did any one experience somthing like this before?

Comment: Why not just change the name of the app and publish an update with the new name?

Comment: Hey there, I'd love to just change the name, but in the info.plist I may only change the Name on the iPhone. And it appears in iTunes Connect I can't change the name of an already approved app.

Comment: Never mind, it appears Apple just wants us to submit a new version with the new Name of the Application...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi unfortunately this is not possible if you are creating a new app to migrate users from an existing app free of charge.

If the old app is still on iTunes, you can just change the name there and in your plist file and continue to use the same bundle identifier, Your old users will receive the new application as a free update, however it sounds like your application has been removed

One option would be to make the app available for free for a period and before any marketing campaign took place, then inform the users of the old application that the new application is available free of charge if they update now, once it is felt you have enough of your old users on the application you could raise the pricing tier of the new application